# JMeter 5.2.1 - Connection properties is ignored

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter, database-connection, apache-commons-dbcp

I checked using JMeter [5.2.1](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1-rc4) the [connection properties](https://apache.github.io/jmeter-site-preview/site/changes.html) feature with oracle

> Bug 63926 - JDBC Connection Configuration: Add ability to set connection properties

But even if I give wrong values in [Oracle connection options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html) as

```
 user=notexists;internal_logon=irrelevant
```

JDBC request is executing normal, meaning it didn't use the wrong connection properties

JMeter uses dbcp2's [BasicDataSource](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.java#L1725) connection properties, but it seems to be ignoring when sending JDBC queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it in 5.2.1 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from ojdbc10.jar downloaded from OTN and it works ok (it takes the properties). 
In the "JDBC Connection Configuration", did you set the "JDBC Driver Class" as "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". 
You also need to add ojdbc10.jar in JMETER_HOME/lib/ext.

Comment: The JDBC works, but when adding **wrong** user in connection properties, it still works although it should failed

Comment: If I put user and password in the properties eg "user=scott;password=tiger" it works as expected (and doesn't connect with a wrong user). However if you set the user in "Username" from the Database Connection Configuration panel then you have to set the "Password" in that panel as well (ie: you either user everything in the properties or in the panel). Are you setting everything in the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the images from Pablo. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]